# booktabs and tiny horizontal space

Tags: tables, spacing, booktabs

In a regular table, I'm trying to remove the small horizontal space before the first column and after the last one as achieved with package `booktabs` with the option `@{}`. How can I do that? Please compile the code below:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}} \toprule
Gnat & per gram & 13.65 \\
Gnu & stuffed & 92.50 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr} \toprule
Gnat & per gram & 13.65 \\
Gnu & stuffed & 92.50 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `@{}` specification in `tabular` works with any table; it's not specific to `booktabs`.

Comment: too bad! I tried few minutes ago and I did not notice it worked. Thanks. I see why I missed it. Option `@{}` has no effect on colored rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@{}` specification in `tabular` works with any table.  It's not specific to the `booktabs` package.

Here's an example with `\fbox`es around the table to show the boundaries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ll}
foo & bar\\
bar & foo
\end{tabular}}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
foo & bar\\
bar & foo
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3):

The **colortbl** commands `\columncolor` and `\rowcolor` add a overhang to the colored cells in order to connect them; the default value of the overhang is `\tabcolsep`; if you color by columns you can specify the left and right overhangs  as optional arguments to `\columncolor`; for `\rowcolor` it's more difficult, as the same overhang is used for all cells in a row:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{l<{\hspace{2pt}}
                >{\hspace{2pt}}l<{\hspace{2pt}}
                >{\hspace{2pt}}r}
\toprule
\rowcolor{green}
Gnat & per gram & 13.65 \\
\rowcolor{blue}
Gnu & stuffed & 92.50 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

In other words, you emulate the `\tabcolsep` space between columns by inserting space manually. With colored rows I would stick to the normal `\tabcolsep` space also before and after the table.

Comment: the `colortbl` package offers an option to control horizontal space for row coloring as follows: `\rowcolor{blue!5}[0pt][0pt]`. By adding an extra empty column in the middle I could achieve what I wanted, i.e. `\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}r@{}p{5cm}@{}} \hline 
\rowcolor{blue!5}[0pt][0mm]0&\hphantom{0}& text \\ 
10&& text \\\hline\end{tabular}\end{table}`

Comment: @pluton The cell won't be connected, with this setting, unless you set also `\tabcolsep` to 0pt; with the trick there will still be a small overhang that's necessary with `l` or `r` columns and the widest entry in `c` columns.