# fbox in tabular throws missing endgroup

Tags: tables, captions, framed

I have to draw a border around my tables, so I'm using `\fbox{}` (is there a better way?). It works when using a `threeparttable` but with the normal `tabular` latex throws an error stating

```
Missing \endgroup inserted
```

I have closed the curly brackets. What am I missing? I've found the post [booktabs and tiny horizontal space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/booktabs-and-tiny-horizontal-space) where it seems to work. See the code below:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\fbox{
\centering\caption{\textbf{blabla 1}}
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lc}
\toprule 
\textbf{SF-36 Parameter} & \textbf{Mittelwert (SD)}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Körperliche Funktionsfähigkeit & 56,5 (33,6)\tabularnewline
\midrule 
Psychisches Wohlbefinden & 70,7 (17,8)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You are trying to enclose the `\caption` within the `\fbox`. Is this what you're after?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's what I want to do...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28412/framed-text-with-a-float-in-it. See if the provided link helps you. It suggests using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and specifying the float style as `boxed`. If not, let us know.

Comment: Hi Werner, your speed is amazing :-) But no, unfortunately this is not precisly what I'm looking after. As shown above, the frame is supposed to be drawn around both the caption and the table. I could live without the caption, but the float package puts the caption above the table. This is surely not what I want...

Comment: I thought you wanted the caption above the table? That's how it is in your MWE. LaTeX considers figures and tables as floats, which it handles in a specific way. Apart from that, you can put a table in a `figure` environment and *vice versa*. It's just that the one is associated with the LoF and the other with the LoT.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It puts the caption *below* the table, not above. I do want them above.

Comment: `\fbox` works if you put it around a `minipage`. I would go with Mico's answer on @Werner's link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) to draw a box around the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,xcolor=true]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{mdframed}[
    tikzsetting={align=center,draw=red,ultra thick,align=center},
    innerrightmargin=5pt,innerleftmargin=5pt,innerbottommargin=5pt
    ]
\begin{center}
\caption{\textbf{blabla 1}}
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lc}
\toprule 
\textbf{SF-36 Parameter} & \textbf{Mittelwert (SD)}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Körperliche Funktionsfähigkeit & 56,5 (33,6)\tabularnewline
\midrule 
Psychisches Wohlbefinden & 70,7 (17,8)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
\end{mdframed}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case you should use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`

Comment: One last thing. When I use both mdframed and begin/end centering (see the code below), then the table is still not centered.
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{mdframed}[style=schwarzelinie]
    \begin{centering}\caption{blabla}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.9\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lc}
    \toprule 
    SF-36 Parameter & Mittelwert (SD)\tabularnewline
     \midrule
     \midrule 
     Körperliche Funktionsfähigkeit & 56,5 (33,6)\tabularnewline
     \end{tabular*}\end{centering}
     \end{mdframed}
     \end{table}
See this [image](http://s14.directupload.net/images/111220/f6t6ggxe.png).

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks. Have added that and now the table is properly centered.

Comment: @Jan: You need `begin{center}` instead of `\begin{centering}`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could define a new environment for your framed tables, like so (using `fancybox`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{caption}  % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{fancybox} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox

\newlength{\mylength}%
\setlength{\mylength}{\textwidth}%
\addtolength{\mylength}{-2\fboxsep}%
\addtolength{\mylength}{-2\fboxrule}%

\newenvironment{FramedTable}%
  {\begin{table}[h]%
     \begin{Sbox}%
       \begin{minipage}{\mylength}%
         \centering}%
  {    \end{minipage}%
     \end{Sbox}\fbox{\TheSbox}%
   \end{table}}%

\begin{document}

\section*{Framed Tables!}

\begin{FramedTable}
  \caption{Hello World}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
    \toprule
    Apple & Banana & Cherry\\
    \midrule
    One & Two & Three\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{FramedTable}

\end{document}
```

This code yields:

[image: MWE solution for OP's question]

Comment: Gorgeous. You can't use it in Lyx though.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were using LyX. I've never used LyX, so I'm unfamiliar with what works and what doesn't work. Perhaps then you should consider Peter Grill's answer. `mdframed` is a great and easy to use package. :)

Comment: Lyx gives some nasty graphical security ;-) I am indeed using Peter's answer but defining a new environment looked very impressive.

Answer (score 3):

`\fbox{..}` enforces *restricted horizontal mode* on its content, i.e. you can't have paragraphs in them, except if you add a `\parbox` or `minipage` yourself. You need to use a framing environment which allows vertical mode inside it.

Besides the mentioned `mdframed` there is also the `adjustbox` environment from the package with the same name, if used with the `minipage` and `fbox` option.

You should also reverse the skip above and below the `\caption` because by default it is designed to go below things, so `\belowcaptionskip` is normally empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,fbox}
\centering
\belowcaptionskip\abovecaptionskip
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\caption{\textbf{blabla 1}}
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lc}
\toprule 
\textbf{SF-36 Parameter} & \textbf{Mittelwert (SD)}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Körperliche Funktionsfähigkeit & 56,5 (33,6)\tabularnewline
\midrule 
Psychisches Wohlbefinden & 70,7 (17,8)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```