# How to trim the length of \toprule?

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

How to trim `\toprule` (from `booktabs` package)?

It is probably something basic I'm missing, but I need it and it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: By trimming you mean making it thinner or the spacing after it?

Comment: `\toprule[1mm]` for example

Comment: The latter -- want to make it shorter so that it begins and ends with the table contents, i.e. similar thing as the `(lr)` thing does to `\cmidrule(lr)`.

Comment: Related: [booktabs and tiny horizontal space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32844). (The horizontal space (`2\tabcolsep`) that is usually inserted between columns is also inserted before and after the first and the last column (but only one `\tabcolsep`).)

Answer (score 12):

If I understand your objective correctly, you want the lines generated by `\toprule` -- and by `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` too, right? -- start at the left-hand edge and end at the right-hand edge of the *contents* of the table.

To achieve this objective, you could specify `@{}` as the first and last items in the argument of a `tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, etc. environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ @{} lccr @{} } % @{} suppresses the whitespace in the corresponding position
\toprule
long story & about & absolutely & nothing \\
\midrule
aa & bb & cc & dd\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{First thoughts \dots }\\     % note the @{} item before "l"
& & \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\dots Final thoughts}\\  % note the @{} item after "r"
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The MWE also illustrates that if your table has `\multicolumn` directives that encompass the first or final columns of the table, you'll again need to supply `@{}` items, as appropriate, this time in the second argument of the `\multicolumn` command.

By the way, I believe that suppressing the whitespace at the far left and far right edges of a table is something that the author of the `booktabs` package recommends doing; see, e.g., the `tabular` environment at the top of page 5 of the package's [user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf); the output of that code is shown on p. 2 of the guide.