# How to trim the length of \toprule

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I want to be able to trim the left and the right of a `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` as you can do with `\cmidrule(lr){<column range>}`. My attempted solution using `\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{<column range>}` comes pretty close, but unfortunately does not quite align vertically with what a `\toprule`/`\bottomrule` produces.

So, the desired output is the table on the left (which uses `\MyToprule` and `\MyBottomrule`), but with the vertical alignment of the table on the right (which uses `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`).

[image]

### Note:

- This question was asked before as [How to trim the length of \toprule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103843/how-to-trim-the-length-of-toprule), but that was closed as a duplicate either because the title was not exactly what was desired or a workaround was sufficient.
- If there is an easier way to obtain the desired output that would be useful.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcounter{MyCounter}

\newcommand*{\NumberRow}{\stepcounter{MyCounter}\arabic{MyCounter}.}%
\newcommand*{\MyToprule}[1]{% #1 = 2-<last column>
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{#1}%
}%
\newcommand*{\MyBottomrule}[1]{% #1 = 2-<last column>
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{#1}%
}%
\newenvironment{MyTabular}[2][]{%
    \setcounter{MyCounter}{0}%
    \tabular[#1]{#2}%
}{%
    \endtabular
}%

\newcommand*{\TabularContent}{%
               & Item Heading & Text Heading \\
               \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
               \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \NumberRow & Item 1  & Some Text \\
               & Item 1a & Some other Text \\
    \NumberRow & Item 2  & Some Text \\
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{MyTabular}{cll}
    \MyToprule{2-3}
       &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule and MyBottomrule} \\
       \TabularContent
    \MyBottomrule{2-3}
\end{MyTabular}%
\begin{MyTabular}{cll}
    \toprule
       &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Using toprule and bottomrule} \\
       \TabularContent
    \bottomrule
\end{MyTabular}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want such a layout: the top and bottom rules are meant to delimit the table from the context, so they should cover also the row numbers. The column with row numbers can have no header, if the role of numbers is clear either from the caption or the headers above the other columns.

If you want to go on with this, just don't define `\MyToprule` and `\MyBottomrule` to have an argument and leave to `\cmidrule` the scanning for arguments.

Note that I fixed the definition of `MyTabular` for the treatment of the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcounter{MyCounter}

\newcommand*{\NumberRow}{\stepcounter{MyCounter}\arabic{MyCounter}.}

\newcommand*{\MyToprule}{%
  \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]%
}

\newcommand*{\MyBottomrule}{%
  \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]%
}
\newenvironment{MyTabular}[2][c]{% Default is centering
    \setcounter{MyCounter}{0}%
    \tabular[#1]{#2}%
}{%
    \endtabular
}

\newcommand*{\TabularContent}{%
               & Item Heading & Text Heading \\
               \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
               \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \NumberRow & Item 1  & Some Text \\
               & Item 1a & Some other Text \\
    \NumberRow & Item 2  & Some Text \\
}


\begin{document}
\begin{MyTabular}{rll}
\MyToprule(lr){2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule} \\
\TabularContent
\MyBottomrule(lr){2-3}
\end{MyTabular}
\end{document}
```

(I changed the double column header to avoid it adding space to the second column.)

[image]

---

Fancier version where the vertical alignment is the same for the customized environment and the normal one (assuming default values for the parameters of `booktabs`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,xparse}

\newcounter{MyCounter}

\newcommand*{\NumberRow}{\stepcounter{MyCounter}\arabic{MyCounter}.}

\newcommand*{\MyToprule}{%
  \addlinespace[-\aboverulesep]%
  \addlinespace[\heavyrulewidth]
  \addlinespace[-2\cmidrulewidth]
  \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]%
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\MyBottomrule}{d()m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{#2}}
   {\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](#1){#2}}%
  \addlinespace[-\belowrulesep]
}
\newenvironment{MyTabular}[2][c]{%
    \setcounter{MyCounter}{0}%
    \tabular[#1]{#2}%
}{%
    \endtabular
}

\newcommand*{\TabularContent}{%
               & Item Heading & Text Heading \\
               \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
               \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \NumberRow & Item 1  & Some Text \\
               & Item 1a & Some other Text \\
    \NumberRow & Item 2  & Some Text \\
}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

Top alignment:

\begin{MyTabular}[t]{rll}
\MyToprule(lr){2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule} \\
\TabularContent
\MyBottomrule(lr){2-3}
\end{MyTabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{rll}
\toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule} \\
\TabularContent
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Center alignment:\medskip

\begin{MyTabular}{rll}
\MyToprule(lr){2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule} \\
\TabularContent
\MyBottomrule(lr){2-3}
\end{MyTabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}{rll}
\toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule} \\
\TabularContent
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Bottom alignment:\medskip

\begin{MyTabular}[b]{rll}
\MyToprule(lr){2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule} \\
\TabularContent
\MyBottomrule(lr){2-3}
\end{MyTabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}[b]{rll}
\toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Using MyToprule} \\
\TabularContent
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is definitely a good suggestion, but the two tables (one using `\MyToprule` and `\MyBottomrule` and the other using `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` as I set up in the MWE) are not vertically aligned.

Comment: @PeterGrill I added a version for fixed vertical alignment. But I still can't understand your purpose.

Comment: Thanks. The alignment still seems _slightly_ off (if you put the tables right next to each other, the `\toptule`s and `\bottomrules` don't exactly continue on, but this more than adequate for what I need.

Comment: @PeterGrill Well, those tables are wrong to begin with. `;-)`

Comment: Oh, the reason I want the numbering outside the table is that I number my examples using enumerated lists. In a few rare cases the examples are better presented in a tabular layout so the numbering is to indicate separate examples. Keeping the numbering outside of the rules, makes the examples presented with a table consistent with the list examples.  Also, sorry the delay in responding -- had issues with my Mac.